# Python loop returns false answers and I don't understand why

Tags: python, algorithm, list

Here is my code:

```
def readTogether(path):
    ins = open(path, "r")
    array = []  # Filtered result
    for line in ins:
        line = line.replace('\n', '')  # Remove empty lines
        while '  ' in line:
            line = line.replace('  ', ' ')  # Remove white space
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.split(' ')
        for elem in line:
            # Make sure each element is entered as integer
            array.append(int(elem))
    ins.close()
    return array

mylist = readTogether('B:\Desktop\input.txt') # http://pastebin.com/rDfYCgxP
someint = 0

# n is every number from 0 to the lenght of mylist
for n in range(0, len(mylist)):
    # for each "letter" in the n object of mylist (converted to a string)
    for x in str(mylist[n]):
        # for how many "letters" are in mylist[n]
        for y in range(0, len(str(mylist[n]))):
            someint += ((int(x) * (int(y) + 1)))
    print(someint, end=' ')
    someint = 0
```

The idea is to take every integer and add together the digit * location(digit). For example, `1776` would be `1*1 + 7*2 + 7*3 + 6*4 = 60`

Expected outcome was:

```
13 8 23 81 8 5 0 122 175 203 60 94 210 9 87 66 28 16 21 6 4 0 36 60 36 43 94 42 53 96 12 170 99 141 98 25 96 158 13
```

Actual outcome:

```
27 18 45 375 36 5 0 936 1440 1620 210 390 1512 15 567 220 66 27 36 18 4 0 170 270 120 108 435 150 345 728 36 1485 525 1575 728 60 405 1665 150 405 1665 21
```

Any help is appreciated, since I'm a newbie to Python

Comment: You are using the Python `list` type; there is a `array` module as well but that's a different kettle of fish altogether.

Comment: @MartijnPieters thanks for pointing that out! Any idea why the code is not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to loop over x and y at the same time, e.g. change:

```
 for x in str(mylist[n]):
    # for how many "letters" are in mylist[n]
    for y in range(0, len(str(mylist[n]))):
        someint += ((int(x) * (int(y) + 1)))
```

to

```
 for y,x in enumerate(str(mylist[n])):
      someint += ((int(x) * (y + 1)))
```

Your current code is looping over each digit x, and then for each digit adding that digit * 1, then that digit * 2, etc., where you only want to include each digit in the sum once.

Answer (score 1):

here is an example with enumerate built-in function:

```
mylist = [['1', '7', '7', '6']] # http://pastebin.com/rDfYCgxP
someint = 0

# n is every number from 0 to the lenght of mylist
for value in mylist:
    someint = 0
    for i, number in enumerate(value, start=1):
        someint += i * int(number)
    print someint
```

What does enumerate do? It returns an enumerate object, a list of tuples where first value is an index and second value is a value from given list, e.g:

```
>>> seasons = ['Spring', 'Summer', 'Fall', 'Winter']
>>> list(enumerate(seasons))
[(0, 'Spring'), (1, 'Summer'), (2, 'Fall'), (3, 'Winter')]
>>> list(enumerate(seasons, start=1))
[(1, 'Spring'), (2, 'Summer'), (3, 'Fall'), (4, 'Winter')]
```

For more information about enumerate please visit the [documentation page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).